# How to show past dates as disabled dates in kendo date picker

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker, kendodaterangepicker

Hi I am using [Kendo Date Picker for Kendo Angular UI.](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/date-ranges/) 
I am using min and max attribute of date picker to restrict user to select from specific range of date. But this completely Hide the out of the range dates likes this.

[image]

Instead I wanted to show them as disabled just like 29th February is disabled. Again this has been disabled using [this api of kendo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/disabled-dates/)

Here the best case is to use min and max as it provide built-in validation, but when we cant controle them from outer CSS BECAUSE DOM ELEMENT ITSELF is not generating any dates and instead it shows the following tag

```
<td class="k-empty">&nbsp;</td>
```

here is what I am doing in HTML

```
  <kendo-datepicker [id]="getId('startDate')"
                            [formatPlaceholder]="{ year: 'YYYY', month: 'MM', day: 'DD' }"
                            [navigation]="false" [min]="minimumDate"
                            (open)="onDatePickerOpen()" formControlName="startDate"></kendo-datepicker>
```

here Opendatepicker function disabled some of the dates based on busienss logic for example Feb 29th is disabled.

How to achieve this disabled look while still following min-max date range API ?

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: Hey I just updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min` and `max` attributes hides the dates out of range, so for disabling You can use [`disabledDates`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/disabled-dates/) directive of `kendo-datepicker`

```
<kendo-datepicker
      [(ngModel)]="value"
      [disabledDates]="disabledDates"
    >
</kendo-datepicker>
```

TS:

```
public disabledDates = (date: Date): boolean => {
    return date < this.minimumDate;
}
```

**[Working Demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w6kpz6?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks a lot , I am trying this out, will it preserve the validation?  (I mean disabling keyboard input, thought thats secondary issue but I am curious. )

Comment: yes it will throw validation error, but will not restrict the input, so you would have to do that manually

Comment: you can check inputs at stackblitz link i provided

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't find any solution with `min` and `max` attributes.

To achieve what you want you can use the **Disable Dates** API to disable every even date in the DatePicker : [Docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/disabled-dates/)

Example :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <kendo-datepicker
      [(ngModel)]="value"
      [disabledDates]="disabledDates"
    >
    </kendo-datepicker>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public value: Date;

  public disabledDates = (date: Date): boolean => {
    const min  = new Date(2019, 1, 1);
    const max = new Date(2022, 1, 1);
    return date < min || date > max;
  }
}
```